# Possible to plug USB-C dock into desktop PC? (re: not working)

Tags: desktop-computer, usb-c, docking-station

Is it possible to use a USB-C dock on a desktop machine?

I'm trying to use a [SteamDock Pro](https://skullnco.com/collections/top-selling/products/steamdock?variant=44494667645220) (USB-C dock) with my PC ([ASUS Z790-F Strix motherboard](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-z790-f-gaming-wifi-model/)) and it doesn't work with either USB-C or USB-A (3.2) ports.

Comment: It doesn't mention PC or Mac on their website but you're probably better off emailing their support team and ask them directly: support@skullnco.com